# Navigation bar not appear properly in IOS 13

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios13

[image]

In here, I have hide the default navigation bar and created a custom navigation bar. When run on iOS 13 device using Xcode 11 two navigation bars showing.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
}
```

[image]

Navigation bar not aligned to the top of the screen properly after updating to iOS 13

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you seek for help, you should post some code to show us what you did.

Comment: Please post your storyboard View's hierarchy from (Document outline section).

Comment: I've had this happen to me too. Then when I demonstrated the app to a colleague the problem vanished, only to reappear again next week. It appears to be associated with the safe area layout guide. Maybe its not always safe?

Answer (score 1):

Try the [safeAreaLayoutGuide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/2891102-safearealayoutguide?language=objc)

Apple: The layout guide representing the portion of your view that is unobscured by bars and other content.

Answer (score 0):

In your viewcontroller, if you want to use the full screen and override the navigationbar entirely with your own subclass, then make sure you do this in the initilizer and the viewwill appear methods

[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:true animated:true];
   [self setExtendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars:true];

from there, you have to access the values of the top layoutguide which will be 44 points and 20 points depending on the size of the iphone you accesss those this way in loadview or viewdidload or a custom subclass

UIWindow *window = UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow;
   CGFloat topPadding = window.safeAreaInsets.top;

then the frame of your custom navigation bar is then calculated like so:

CGRect tempRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, topPadding + 44);

44 is there because it's constant across all iphones and ipads for now (this could change in the future and nullify this solution, but this is the standard for now)

that will return correct dimensions for all iphone sizes.

THIS => [self setExtendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars:true];

IS ABSOLUTELY necessary to make this work as i explained. this isn't a good idea to travel down this path because very rarely do you ever need to override and replace the navigation bar with some custom UIView, but if you need to do it, this is how you do it. Just know that this will break if you're not updating frame sizes during on call status and other edge case conditions.